How are lines defined in 3d file formats?
I was recently using a 2D polygon format for a project and noticed that the lines between coordinates are based on it knowing which points have a line between them.
This information is not expressly stored - it is inferred by the fact that any 2 coordinates which are next to each other in the data format must have a line between them.
Which leads to my question.
In 3D file formats how are lines stored since any co-ordinate can have any number of lines between it and other coordinates. Lines can no longer be inferred by the co-ordinates position in the list of co-ordinates.

please pick a specific format, then find its specification.

Possibilities are infinite. Typically there's either a line consisting of N points connected in order, looped or not OR bunch of points and lines reference them by their indexes.
